# r ggplot mutiple lines - how to show different color instead of gradient

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame like below:

`head(df)`

```
index 2016-07 2016-08 2016-09 2016-10 2016-11 2016-12 2017-01 2017-02 2017-03
1     1    30.5   31.75      32    34.5   39.75   39.75   37.75      36      36
2     2    30.5   31.75      32    34.5   39.75   39.75   37.75      36      36
3     3    30.5   31.75      32    34.5   39.75   39.75   37.75      36      36
4     4    30.5   31.75      32    34.5   39.75   39.75   37.75      36      36
```

Basically there are 250 rows , each row for each date I have a number. I want to put all 250 lines on the same plot which I thought would be super easy but actually not. According to other posts I have read, i used `melt` to break it down and got the following:

```
 index variable value
1     1  2016-07  30.5
2     2  2016-07  30.5
3     3  2016-07  30.5
4     4  2016-07  30.5
5     5  2016-07  30.5
6     6  2016-07  30.5
```

and then by `ggplot2()` I used

```
ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group = index,color=index)) +
geom_line()+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),axis.text=element_text(size=5))+ ggtitle(paste0(comdtylist[k]," ",string))}
```

Unfortunately by doing this I can only get the graph whose color is gradient.

[image]
Now I just want the lines to be different colors instead of gradient - how can I do that?

Comment: It's going to be hard to find 250 different colors, however you can use `color = factor(index)` inside the `aes`

Comment: use colour = `factor(index)` - and convert your date to a Date so it plots nicely

Comment: You need to rethink your approach to visualization. Overlaying the lines is not effective and a 250 color palette is not practical. What is it that you want the chart to convey?

Comment: `@GGamba` `@Richard Telford`   `factor(index)`some how doesn't work - all the lines become black. The reason that I want to do this is to eye spot any abnormality to ensure my simulation algorithm works. I can do it fast in excel- where all lines are in different colors. But excel is not convenient when I have 100 of these kind of curves with 250 simulations for each curve

Comment: If you used `color=as.factor(index)` inside `aes`, the colors should not have become black. Check e.g. `m <- as.data.frame(cbind(seq_len(20), replicate(20, runif(20))));mdf <- reshape2::melt(m, 1);names(mdf)[1] <- "index";ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group = index,color=index)) + geom_line();ggplot(data=mdf, aes(x=variable, y=value, group = index,color=factor(index))) + geom_line()`.